# unicode error with codecs when reading a pdf file in python

Tags: python, pdf, unicode

I am trying to read a pdf file with the following contain:

```
%PDF-1.4\n%âãÏÓ
```

If I read it with open, it works but if I try with codecs.open(filename, encoding="utf8", mode="rb") to get a unicode string, I got the following exception:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 10: invalid continuation byte
```

Do you know a way to get a unicode string from the content of this file?

PS: I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PDFs are made of binary data, not text. They cannot be meaningfully represented as Unicode strings.

For what it's worth, you can get a Unicode string containing those particular characters by treating the PDF as ISO8859-1 text:

```
f = codecs.open(filename, encoding="ISO8859-1", mode="rb")
```

But at that point, you're better off just using normal `open` and reading bytes. Unicode is for text, not data.

Comment: what I don't understand is why you can open it with open (ie as an ascii string) but not as a unicode one while you can still have u"\xe2" as a valid string

Comment: You were trying to read the file in as a UTF-8 string. Only certain sequences of bytes are valid UTF-8 data; the one in the header of the PDF is not valid.

Comment: @trez The `\xe2` in `'\xe2'` (string) and `u"\xe2"` (unicode string) don't mean the same thing. In the former, it's a literal byte. In the latter, it's the Unicode code point. It just happens to be the case that for â, the Latin-1 representation is the byte \xe2, and the Unicode codepoint U+00E2. It's (for practical purposes) just a coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

The issue of trying to interpret arbitrary binary data as text aside, 0xe2 is â in Latin-1, not UTF-8. You're using the wrong codec.

Comment: not really, my editor thing it's latin1 and display it as â but in fact that's only the value 0xe2

Comment: Editors do best guesses based on normally found text file contents. PDF is not a text file. Thus, your editor's guess is meaningless.